a problem with a dictionary in Python:naive approach doesn't work
I have a problem with accessing an dictionary AS item like this:
def T():
    AS = {"fen": {'used': 0, 'to_end': None, 'depth': 1, 'type': 'normal'}}
    return {fen: (data['to_end'], data['type']) for fen, data in AS.items() if data['to_end'] is not True}
s = "fen"
AS = T()

if s in AS and AS[s]['used'] == 0:   
    print(AS)

gives this error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 7
      4 s = "fen"
      5 AS = T()
----> 7 if s in AS and AS[s]['used'] == 0:   
      8     # Tisk hodnot
      9     print(AS)

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

I know a workaround but I wish to grasp in detail why this approach fails. (and how to fix it with a minimum amount of effort)

fen: (data['to_end'], data['type']) - you are assigning a tuple here, not a dictionary like in AS.

If you print the value of T() you will see what is wrong - {'fen': (None, 'normal')}.

@matszwecja Good! How to fix it without AS[s][0] workaround ?

Do basic debugging before posting here, e.g. use https://pythontutor.com/. AS[s][0] isn't a workaround, it's how you access the first value in the tuple. If you want the value of AS (and therefore of AS[s]) to be different, first you'd need to know: what should it contain? Perhaps T (better naming would benefit everyone) is wrong?

@user1642683 I'm not sure why you are only returning data['to_end'], data['type'] in the fen key, but then you are trying to access 'used' key that you didn't put there at all.

@matszwecja I've meant to return an entire AS but apparently I didn't do so.

Why not return AS then? Or if you still want to filter, you can do simply {fen: data for fen, data in...

@matszwecja Yes, returning AS is the best solution for me.

In your T() function, you return a dictionary where the values are tuples, not dictionaries. When you try to access AS[s]['used'], you're attempting to use string indexing on a tuple, which is not possible - hence the error "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str".
here is a slightly modified version of the code snippet.
def T():
    AS = {"fen": {'used': 0, 'to_end': None, 'depth': 1, 'type': 'normal'}}
    return {fen: data for fen, data in AS.items() if data['to_end'] is not None}

s = "fen"
AS = T()

if s in AS and AS[s]['used'] == 0:   
    print(AS)

I also changed the condition if data['to_end'] is not True to if data['to_end'] is not None. This is because in your original dictionary, 'to_end' was set to None, not True. You can change this if you want to.

You should do :
if s in AS and AS[s][0] == 0: 

instead of
if s in AS and AS[s]['used'] == 0: 

By doing AS[s] you access the value of the dict associated with the key s. The value is a tuple, you cannot acces a tuple value by label, you have to use an index to access a tuple value. Here the index of the data you're looking for is 0.
